# Why filtering for trend estimation?

Tags: time-series, trend

I'm starting to learn about techniques for trend removal of a time series with no seasonal component, i.e. $X_t = m_t + Y_t$. If I undertsnad correctly, there are all sorts of filter we can apply in order to estimate $m_t$. An example provided in my book is a finite moving average filter, another example is the Spencer 15-point moving average...

I'm bit confused about why we are using this approach. Why not just apply regression techniques to estimate $m_t$ ? This filtering approach seems very ad-hoc.

Comment: If you want to use regression, you need to assume something about the form of the trend.

Comment: People often apply regression techniques to estimate trends.  The choice of regression technique depends strongly on the primary objectives of the researcher (i.e. to forecast or accurately estimate unobserved signal) and how elaborate/complex they are willing to go.  A simple OLS regression would estimate $m_t$ as a constant.  If you wanted $m_t$ to change dynamically with time then there are several non-parametric regressions you could use (see LOESS/LOWESS and kernel regression).  Other parametric techniques that are useful for forecasting are dynamic regression and the Kalman filter.